# How do I use the Facebook graph api to get recommendations froma site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to programatically get the recommendations(most shared items) from a particular site(not necessarily owned by me,eg. http://www.yourtube.com) using the Graph api. Today I can use the Recommendations Social plugin to get recommendations displayed on a webpage. How do I programatically get the same content using the Graph api?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this via the api, but they do have social widget that you can display that will do something like this.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/